# Is " [&](int i) " casting to a reference in tbb parallel for?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb, dynamic-cast

I am trying to import a code which uses tbb to my project but I don't understand the notation in parallel for loop.This is the first time I am seeing this notation and haven't seen anywhere else.

```
    tbb::parallel_for( 0, static_cast<int>(centers.size()), 1, [&](int k) {
        ColorRep center = centers[k];
```

What does `"[&](int k)"` mean here ? Is it kind of casting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It denotes a C++ lambda- specifically, one which implicitly captures local variables by reference and takes as argument `int i`.

Comment: So can this be used in traditional for loop or it is specific to parallel for ?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan It's a generic c++ construct. Commonly seen used by std:for_each and its ilk.

Comment: It's just a plain language feature that creates expressions out of functions that can reference local variables. It can be used in any context where a callable object is accepted.